# Do iptables rules I put in place on my admin account carry over to a newly created standard user account?

Tags: iptables

Do iptables rules I put in place on my admin account carry over to a newly created standard user account?

Is there a way to verify this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking if you add an iptable rule as root do affect other users, then YES. Iptables are kernel thing so it is the lower level of rules. For example if you are using firewall like CSF and you ban/drop/deny specific ip, the program (CSF) will just translate your ban to an iptables rule and the kernel will start to drop packages from that IP.